# nested ng-repeat on two separate arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs

More than finding a way to resolve this, I am now interested in understanding why this is not working.

Let's say I have this array in angular:

```
 $scope.movieThemes = [ 'Fiction', 'Drama'];
```

And another array with with movies like:

```
$scope.movies=[{theme:'Drama', movie:'One million dollar baby'}, {theme:'Drama', movie:'Green mille'},{theme:'Fiction', movie:'Avatar'}, {theme:'Fiction', movie:'The Hobbit'}]
```

I have an **ngRepeat** with my themes

```
<div ng-repeat= "t in movieThemes">
```

And a nested **datalist** filtering the themes:

```
ng-repeat="m in movies|filter:{theme:t}
```

Where **t** is from the parent repeater like:

```
 <datalist id="movieList">
    <option ng-repeat="m in movies|filter:{theme:t}" value="{{m.movie}} - {{t}}"></option>
  </datalist>
```

OK as you can confirm on my fiddle this is not working:

**[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/revtLzak/)**

But the question is why not?

Worth to mentioned without a data list it works fine:

[Without Data List Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kjdg27fy/1/)

Comment: except syntax error your fiddle seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/v2jkzuhp/. downvoted

Comment: Fiddle didn't match the code in question. it seems someone altered it but my question even in your "fixed" fiddle is still not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this. i change your `filter` function syntax and also add `select` tag to `dataList`.

**Edit:**
Your problem cuase for `datalist` id. i.e your `datalist` ids in `ne-repeat` are same. i change `datalist` ids by adding `$index` to it. now it work correctly.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ["$scope",function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.movieThemes = [ 'Fiction', 'Drama'];
$scope.movies=[
  {theme:'Drama', movie:'One million dollar baby'},
  {theme:'Drama', movie:'Green mille'},
  {theme:'Fiction', movie:'Avatar'}, 
  {theme:'Fiction', movie:'The Hobbit'}
];
  

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat= "t in movieThemes">
  <input  type="text" ng-model="t"  />
  {{t}} - {{$index}} <input type="text"  placeholder="Users" list="movieList{{$index}}">
     <datalist id="movieList{{$index}}">
        <select>
            <option  ng-repeat="m in movies|filter:{theme:t}" value="{{m.movie}} - {{t}}"></option>
         </select>
     </datalist>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your sample code, the Drama drop down is still showing only fiction movies when I expected to see Drama Movies only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupBy filter. This way you don't need wot worry about themes array. You can write your own/use angular filters module.(https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter)

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in movies| groupBy: 'theme'">
    Group name: {{ key }}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="m in value">
        player: {{ m.movie}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

BTW I like angular filters modules

Comment: Thanks although this is an alternate solution, I am interested in understanding why datalist nested ngRepeat does not work in angular.

Comment: U had some errors in data list one. See this , its working. http://jsfiddle.net/kjdg27fy/2/